# show the list of post

Tags: django, django-views

I am making a page that shows the list of post, which was in my blog, but the problem is, I just want to show 3 posts each page, if user clicks next, they can see the next 3 posts, or click previous to see the previous page. How can I do that? if the code is too long, you can just tell me how can I do that. I am thinking of using loop, but with previous function is a bad idea. Thanks for your reading and hope to see your reply soon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [django pagination](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/pagination/). If you use generic [`ListView`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#listview) then pagination will be done automatically by providing [`paginate_by`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/class-based-views/mixins-multiple-object/#django.views.generic.list.MultipleObjectMixin.paginate_by) parameter.

Comment: thanks for your quick reply, it is very useful. I am reading it. I will tell you when I try it completely

Comment: I added link to `paginate_by` documentation.